# How can I determine which installed fonts can display a certain glyph?

Tags: fonts

Given a glyph (eg: ''), how do I determine which (if any!) fonts contain it?

That particular glyph displays in firefox, so presumably it's on my system, but I've not been able to get it displayed in a python-generated pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `gucharmap`. You can search for a given character (say, `ã`), and also dynamically change the font used to display that character (e.g. `Liberation Sans` to something else).

[image]

Comment: Nice - thanks. Once you find a glyph, right click to see which font it's being displayed as. If it's not in the selected font, it shows you a font that contains it. It doesn't seem to give you a list of fonts that contain your glyph, but that's ok (:

Comment: Sorry for necro, but how can you change the font used to display the character? I can't find that option.

Comment: @palmerito0 In `gucharmap` 3.10.1 you can easily change the font from the main UI. See added screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Try landroni's answer, but with the advent of WebFonts, there is no guarantee that any particular font or glyph is going to be resident on your system if you only see the glyph rendered on webpages. You can use the Web Developer Tools (Tools->Web Developer->Inspector) in Firefox to inspect the contents of a webpage to see if WebFonts are being used.

Comment: inspecting the `<p>` tag containing the  '' in the question, it's using the symbola font, which I've installed in my `~/.fonts` folder. Seems an ok way to find which font it is (: